# jQuery Validation - skip_or_fill_minimum rule does not fire if it is used more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have a form that is composed by four inputs, and they're grouped in pairs.

The rule for this form is very simple, if I fill out one of the inputs of the pair, I have to fill out the other too or I don't fill out any, so to achieve this behaviour I used `skip_or_fill_minimun` method.

**The HTML:**

```
<div id="msgErros"></div>
<form>
    <label for="dataInicial">Data Inicial</label>
    <input type="text" name="filtro.dataInicial" id="dataInicial" class="datas" />
    <label for="dataFinal">Data Final</label>
    <input type="text" name="filtro.dataFinal" id="dataFinal" class="datas" />
    <br />
    <label for="tempoInicial">Tempo Inicial</label>
    <input type="text" name="filtro.tempoInicial" id="tempoInicial" class="tempos" />
    <label for="tempoFinal">Tempo Final</label>
    <input type="text" name="filtro.tempoFinal" id="tempoFinal" class="tempos" />
    <br />
    <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

**The validation rules, messages and groups:**

```
$("form").validate({
    rules : {
        "filtro.dataInicial": {
            skip_or_fill_minimum: [2, ".datas"]
        },
        "filtro.dataFinal": {
            skip_or_fill_minimum: [2, ".datas"]
        },
        "filtro.tempoInicial": {
            skip_or_fill_minimum: [2, ".tempos"]
        },
        "filtro.tempoFinal": {
            skip_or_fill_minimum: [2, ".tempos"]
        }
    },
    messages: {
        "filtro.dataInicial": {
            skip_or_fill_minimum: "Por favor, preencha ambos os campos de data ou nenhum deles."
        },
        "filtro.dataFinal": {
            skip_or_fill_minimum: "Por favor, preencha ambos os campos de data ou nenhum deles."
        },
        "filtro.tempoInicial": {
            skip_or_fill_minimum: "Por favor, preencha ambos os campos de tempo ou nenhum deles."
        },
        "filtro.tempoFinal": {
            skip_or_fill_minimum: "Por favor, preencha ambos os campos de tempo ou nenhum deles."
        }
    },
    groups : {
        grupoDatasAtendimentoSintetico : "filtro.dataInicial filtro.dataFinal",
        grupoTemposAtendimentoSintetico : "filtro.tempoInicial filtro.tempoFinal"
    },
    errorContainer : "#msgErros ul",
    errorLabelContainer : "#msgErros",
    wrapper : "li"
});
```

The problem happening here is that if I fill out one of the first two inputs the rule isn't fired at all, the problem does not occur if I do it with the second pair. If I delete the second pair the rule executes just fine so I think this is a bug. Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pgioseffi/82g5A/).

I read about this method and `require_from_group` causing problems that simply prevents other methods from being executed but this issue is supposed to be corrected in the version 1.11.1 which is the one I'm using in my project and in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pgioseffi/82g5A/) for both the plugin itself and the additional methods.

The problem happens only when the user fill out one of the fields in the first pair. Does anyone know if this is another bug? I haven't found nothing related to this in the [GitHub issue tracker](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues) of this plugin.

**UPDATE:**

I just placed an [issue](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/1008) in the plugin's issue tracker.

Comment: [Your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pgioseffi/82g5A/) is working just fine for me.  I'm not seeing any issues at all.

Comment: @Sparky, just fill out one of the first two inputs and submit the form and you'll see the problem, you may fill out the last two or not and the problem occurs too.

Comment: Nope... it's still working when I do that.

Comment: Did you submit the form? The message shows up, I know it does, but the form is submitted when it is not supposed to.

Comment: This will be my last comment... yes, I am very familiar with this plugin and how it's supposed to work.  Both instances of your `skip_or_fill_minimum` rule appear to be working the same using multiple combinations of inputs and empty fields.

Comment: You don't have to comment if you don't feel like. I just tested the fiddle again and the form is being submitted.

Comment: @Sparky The version of `skip_or_fill_minimum` that is in the answer is not equals to the one contained in the  http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js file. That's why the bug happens.

Comment: I don't deny it but maybe it's also specific to a browser type/version because I'm definitely not seeing the issue here. Glad you figured it out.

Comment: @Sparky I edited my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/82g5A/3/). Just press submit and you'll see the problem. I'm using chrome, FF and IE on Win 7, all of them in the last versions. OS fully updated.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46978/discussion-between-philippe-and-sparky)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are reporting has been resolved [in a recent commit](https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/commit/e5207d63a831fdfa30ea6927906288ae60336c76#diff-82185dc776c598c0eaf19f2c0f743011).

I've [updated your Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/82g5A/2/). I removed the external dependencies, copied and pasted the code from http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js in the begining of the JavaScript section, followed by the code from http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js - an at the end I kept your JavaScript untouched.

Then, I've picked up the most recent version of "skip_or_fill_minimum" code here: https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/blob/master/src/additional/skip_or_fill_minimum.js

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("skip_or_fill_minimum", function(value, element, options) {
    var $fields = $(options[1], element.form),
        $fieldsFirst = $fields.eq(0),
        validator = $fieldsFirst.data("valid_skip") ? $fieldsFirst.data("valid_skip") : $.extend({}, this),
        numberFilled = $fields.filter(function() {
            return validator.elementValue(this);
        }).length,
        isValid = numberFilled === 0 || numberFilled >= options[0];

    // Store the cloned validator for future validation
    $fieldsFirst.data("valid_skip", validator);

    // If element isn't being validated, run each skip_or_fill_minimum field's validation rules
    if (!$(element).data("being_validated")) {
        $fields.data("being_validated", true);
        $fields.each(function() {
            validator.element(this);
        });
        $fields.data("being_validated", false);
    }
    return isValid;
}, jQuery.validator.format("Please either skip these fields or fill at least {0} of them."));
```

And, finally, pasted this code substituting the prior version which was at the Fiddle.

With this, the problem vanished! From this we conclude that the bug really existed but it has been already fixed.

---

#### Update:

Version 1.11.1 is from March 22, 2013 (https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/tree/1.11.1). The commit which fixes the bug is from August 27, 2013 (https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/commit/e5207d63a831fdfa30ea6927906288ae60336c76)

There is nothing wrong with your code. It is a bug in jQuery Validate. The bug exists in version 1.11.1 - either you wait for a new release, ou you must apply the fix on your own.

To apply the fix , you need to substitute the buggy `skip_or_fill_minimum` code for the most recent one (pasted above). Use the non-minimized version of `additional-methods.js` for this. (You can minimize it later with "uglify.js" or other tool, if you want.)

Comment: @JBruni So could you tell me what was a wrong with my code? If I'm using the latest version of the plugin and the latest of the additional methods why the plugin does doesn't prevent the form from being submittef even if I fill out only one field?

Comment: This version of `skip_or_fill_minimum` is not equals to the one contained in the  http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js file, right?

Comment: Your code is correct. The "latest version" (1.11.1) was published in March 22, 2013 (almost one year old). You indeed have found a bug. But it was already fixed, 5 months ago. The fix is exactly in the `skip_or_fill_minimum` validator method. I will update my answer above with additional info...

Comment: Thanks for your help, should I copy require_from_group too?

Comment: I think this is a good idea. (In this case, it is not **necessary**, because you are using only "skip_or_fill_minimum"; it won't make a difference. But we know that "require_from_group" was also fixed, so it is a good idea to update it too.)

Comment: I use it in another form and since they both have had the same problem I'll update it too.

Comment: @PhilippeGioseffi, The `require_from_group` rule is a very popular method and there have been no (bug) complaints from anyone on SO as long as they're using version 1.11.1.  It seems that you found a bug with `skip_or_fill_minimum`... let's not get carried away by making repetitive comments all over the place that there's also a bug in `require_from_group` when there is not.